# Throwing error to end promise chain

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I've been using reject to end promises but I have a situation using Mongoose (with build in promises) where I need to reject. I am throwing an error and all seems ok. Is this a good idea?

```
my Method = function() {
  return User.findById(id).exec()
    .then(function(user) {
      if(!user) throw new Error('not found');

      // Do stuff that continues chain
      return abc();
    })
    .then(function(abcResult) {

    });
};
```

In my controller the error successfully lands in the promise error function:

```
myMethod('123').then(function(res) {
  //result from abc();
}, function(err) {
   //status 404
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would raise a rejection (possibly by throwing an exception) in any place you're throw an exception in sync code.

Objectively - if you think this is fine in synchronous code:

```
function method(id){
   var user = findById(id);
   if(!user) throw new Error('not found');
   var res = abc();
   return bcdEf(res);
}
```

And having:

```
try{
   var res = myMethod('123');
   // handle result
} catch(e){
   return 404;
}
```

Is fine - then your promise pattern is fine since it models the same thing basically.

Comment: It seems to be working fine without the try/catch block on controller. its landing in the promise error function. Seems ok then?

Comment: That's an analogy to how that code would look like without promises not actual code.